# How can I map JSON fields to struct fields while deserializing?

Tags: json, rust, serde

Given some JSON:

```
{
    "name": "Dude",
    "foo": {
      "bar": "baz"
    }
}
```

Assuming I want to map it to a struct like this:

```rust
struct Chump {
    Name: string,
    Bar: string,
}
```

which means I'd like to map `Chump.Bar` to `foo.bar`, is there any way I can easily achieve this with `serde`? Or any other form of JSON (de)serializer?

The only way I found so far is to use

```rust
#[serde(flatten)]
```

to get a `Map` of whatever gets left after parsing. Is there a better, more efficient way, maybe?

Comment: Your Rust code won't compile. Rust is case sensitive, which means it's not `string`, but [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html). Also fields should be written in camelCase, which means the first character is lowercase (e.g. `name` and `bar). But this is a convention, and not an enforcement. Please fix that and provide a [mcve] best on [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible.